# fdisk: Default partion type "Linux filesystem"

Tags: linux, centos, raid, fdisk, storage

I am using CentOS 8 and added two nvme storage disks, which I want to configure in RAID1 mirror.

Following is `lsblk` output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  1.5T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0  1.5T  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0  1.5T  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0   32G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0  5.1T  0 disk 
nvme1n1     259:2    0  5.1T  0 disk
```

When I am trying to add a partition to `/dev/nvme0n1` and `/dev/nvme1n1` respectively through `fdisk`, the partion being created in `Linux filesystem` by default, when I try to change the partition type to `fd` I get the following error:

```
Type of partition 1 is unchanged: "Linux filesystem"
```

Creating the partition process is going as following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk /dev/nvme0n1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.32.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-5607509301657, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-5607509301657, default 5607509301657): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 5.1 TiB
```

How can I configure the added storage partition in raid autodetect type while it is being created on `Linux filesystem` by default?
.

Comment: What do you mean by `fd`? Is this type known to your `fdisk`? (answer L when it says `Partition type or alias (type L to list all):`).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Linux raid partition with autodetect using persistent superblock

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski more info here: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x190.html

Comment: My `fdisk` "knows" `FD` (aliased to `raid`) when the partition table if of the type `dos` (in MBR). For GPT `fd` is not a valid type, although a `raid` *alias* exists here as well. What do you see when you tell the tool to list available types?

Comment: You are creating a GPT partition table rather than MBR, aren't you...?

Comment: Try running `fdisk` with `FDISK_DEBUG=all LIBFDISK_DEBUG=all`, it should print some more information.

Comment: @roaima how can I tell if it's GPT or MBR?

Comment: You can use `p` to print partition table information. It will say `Disklabel type: dos` for MBR or `Disklabel type: gpt` for GPT.

Comment: Disklabel type: gpt

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the following are related to raid: 
 64 NetBSD RAID &
 29 Linux RAID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fd` is the type code used for Linux RAID by MBR partitioning schemes. But your disk is partitioned using the GPT scheme.

In GPT, the partition type is expressed as a GUID; in case of Linux RAID, the GUID would be

```
A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
```

But that's inconvenient for humans, so most partitioning tools will default to other method rather than requiring you to enter the type GUID directly. In case of a modern, GPT-aware version of `fdisk`, it will present a numbered list of partition types it knows:

```
Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-3, default 3): 2   # this will be omitted if there's only 1 partition
Partition type (type L to list all types): L

 1 EFI System                     C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
 2 MBR partition scheme           024DEE41-33E7-11D3-9D69-0008C781F39F
 3 Intel Fast Flash               D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593
 4 BIOS boot                      21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
[...]
19 Linux swap                     0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F  
20 Linux filesystem               0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
21 Linux server data              3B8F8425-20E0-4F3B-907F-1A25A76F98E8
22 Linux root (x86)               44479540-F297-41B2-9AF7-D131D5F0458A
23 Linux root (ARM)               69DAD710-2CE4-4E3C-B16C-21A1D49ABED3
24 Linux root (x86-64)            4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709
25 Linux root (ARM-64)            B921B045-1DF0-41C3-AF44-4C6F280D3FAE
26 Linux root (IA-64)             993D8D3D-F80E-4225-855A-9DAF8ED7EA97
27 Linux reserved                 8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908
28 Linux home                     933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915
29 Linux RAID                     A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
30 Linux extended boot            BC13C2FF-59E6-4262-A352-B275FD6F7172
31 Linux LVM                      E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928
[...]
```

The exact numbers in the menu may vary between `fdisk` versions, but `Linux RAID` is the type you'll want for your RAID1 configuration. So here you would select number `29`.

The HOWTO document you were following is from year 2009, when UEFI and GPT were still pretty much unknown with PCs: UEFI hit the mainstream with Intel's Sandy Bridge generation of CPUs in 2011, and brought along the ability to use GPT partitioning on boot disks.

---

If you are wondering why GPT has so many Linux partition types, you might want to know that there is an *optional* scheme, usable by modern enough versions of `systemd`, that allows you to designate a partition's purpose by using its GPT type GUID. If your system configuration is relatively simple, this may allow you to leave the `/etc/fstab` file completely empty and let the system auto-detect the required filesystems.

This may make some things easier for the administrators of massive fleets of auto-built VMs or cloud systems: they can prepare the OS root disk, `/home` disk and some other data disk separately, and then just stick them together into a single VM instance and the OS will figure it out as it boots.

You may read more about this scheme here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-gpt-auto-generator.html